# Defining a ChainedMap in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to define a "chained map" after http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html. I have run into a problem defining the companion object `apply` method. Here is what I have come up with:

```
import scala.collection.generic.ImmutableMapFactory
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

class ChainedMap[A, B](private val superMap: ChainedMap[A, B])
  extends HashMap[A, B] {
  override def get(key: A): Option[B] = {
    if (contains(key)) {
      get(key)
    } else if (superMap != null) {
      superMap.get(key)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

object ChainedMap extends ImmutableMapFactory[ChainedMap] {
  override def apply[A, B](superMap: ChainedMap[A, B],
                           elems: (A, B)*): ChainedMap[A, B] = {
    // What goes here?
  }
}
```

Here is how I will use it:

```
val parentMap = ChainedMap(null, "x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)
val childMap = ChainedMap(parentMap, "a" -> 42)
```

Comment: How do you ever create a `ChainedMap` that contains something if the only constructor takes a `ChainedMap` as an argument, and it calls the immutable empty-hash-map constructor?

Comment: I don't really see the point in creating a `ChainedMap` class from immutable HashMaps. You could just create `val parentMap = Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)` and then create `val childMap = parentMap ++ ("a" -> 42)` using support that's already built into the Scala collections library.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Duh! I hadn't thought of that. I guess if the same key appears in both the child and parent, the child one will be found first. I should probably delete the question and save myself the embarrassment.

Comment: @Ralph: the child's version of the key appear *instead* of the parent's version of the key (when you access the child). That means if you're iterating, you'll only see the child's copy of the key. (But you haven't addressed iteration in your question, so it doesn't sound like it's part of your use case.)

Comment: @Ken Bloom: I don't really need to iterate over all keys. I just need to find the "correct" value of a key.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Actually, iteration **should** work, since the "parent" and "child" maps have shared structure. The nice thing about this data structure is that I can add new key-value pairs to the (literal) parent, recompile, and have the child get them too, without maintaining two maps.

Comment: @Ralph - But the parent is immutable as you've defined it.  Do you want to use `mutable.HashMap`?  Having a child change from under you because the parent changed sounds risky / confusing to me for most situations...are you really sure that the standard immutable model isn't the better way to go overall?

Comment: @Rex: he's making changes at compile time, but depending on his intended use, making changes in `parentMap` that reflect in `childMap` could be quite natural, for example when the maps represent inherited permissions that can be changed by some command at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, extending Scala collections is tricky. There's [this reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html), plus some blogs and Stack Overflow questions. However, you don't need to do it, because it is already supported.

```
scala> val parentMap = Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)             
parentMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map((x,1), (y,2))

scala> val childMap = Map("a" -> 42) withDefault parentMap
childMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map((a,42))

scala> childMap("x")
res5: Int = 1
```

Comment: That is sweet! Also look at Ken Bloom's comments above. I did not think about it, but immutable data structures "share" values with the the original structure when they are "updated". Works in Clojure too.

Comment: Daniel's answer will work with mutable maps (if you update the parent, then the changes will be reflected in the child), but my answer won't because ++ creates a new map (that just happens to have shared structure when it's an immutable map). Also, iteration is different.